# DAE model missing faces

Tags: export, faces, dae

I have created a model of a set of shelves that looks fine in Blender. However, when I exported the model as a dae and imported this into Sweet Home 3D, 3 faces, on 2 identical legs, were missing. These were faces that I had had some issues with when using Knife to alter the shape and I had to recreate them. However, it all looked ok, even in Render.

[image: Blender model]

[image: Rendered image]

[image: Imported into Sweet Home]

Any ideas why the dae model would be missing these faces?

Comment: EIther it's normals facing the wrong direction or front-face culling is on. In most cases I've seen, this is a result of wrongly oriented normals. In edit mode, select all, then `Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside`.

Comment: I did find out that an obj was fine. Not ure why dae was different.

Comment: Just curious, when you exported .dae, did you use blender's native Collada (default) .dae export, or the Better Collada Add-on?